# Output the description page property as meta description tag

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, metadata

I do the following in the SharePoint 2010 masterpage and it grabs the Title field from the publishing page property.  I want to do the same for the description field/meta but don't know if there is an easy way to do this.

Works for Title

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server" /> </title>
```

Does not work for Description (at least its not mapped to the page property "Description")

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check which masterpage you are using.  There are multiple masterpages available and they don't all have the same ContentPlaceHolder's.  You can find the masterpage files in the ..\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS directory.

Comment: That didnt help, I looked at V4.master and while they are doing the same as I have mentioned for the Title meta there is nothing for Description meta.